# Swift CoreData: Check uniqueness for paired fields

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, predicate

I have a table that stores multiple UUIDs. I need to check that a particular pair of such UUIDs doesn't already exist – not as a constraint on the table, but within a predicate. Maybe this?:

```
NSPredicate(format: "NOT(userID == %@ AND blockID == %@", user.id as CVarArg, block.id as CVarArg))
```

The inherited project only needed to worry about a pair of ids, and simply concatenated the two ids in each record, and used a string comparison. But now a third is being added, and more might be coming.

How is this best handled?

Comment: Don’t you also need to check if userID == block.id and so on?

Comment: If there is no cross checking then I would use the predicate above but without the NOT and use a count fetch request, [count(for:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext/1506868-count)

Comment: Side note, it's missing a closing parenthesis. I don't know if this make the predicate invalid, or causes a false positive.

Comment: Larme: that wasn't cut paste code, just typed in to the SO box... :)

Comment: Joakim: will give that a whirl tomorrow....